# My login page is not working correctly

Tags: php, session, authentication

I got some help earlier on my registration page but now i cant get my login page going.

Here is the login code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        echo "WELCOME you are logged in";   
    }

    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = shal1($_POST['password']);

        $db = connect('jsnow_jsnow','missysnow2005');
        $eval = validate($db,$username,$password);
    }

    if($eval!=false)
    {
        echo "Welcome ".$eval; 
        $_SESSION['username']=$eval;
    }


    function connect($dbuser, $dbpassword)
    {
        try
        {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jsnow_members', 'jsnow_jsnow', '*******');
            return $db;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e;
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validate($db, $user,$password)
    {
        $username=false;
        $query = "Select username,password FROM jsnow_members where username   ='".$user."' AND password = '".$password."'";
        try
        {
            $db->beginTransaction();
            $result = $db->query($query);

            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $username = $row['username'];   
            }
            $db->commit();

            return $username;
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {}
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="http://vps8383.inmotionhosting.com/~jsnow/login.php">
            username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
            password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

the database name is `jsnow_members` and its fields are `username`, `password` and `email.`

I got this code from a tutorial and it didn't pan out too well obviously, i got the registration page code from the same tutorial and it took a bunch of work and suggestions from people on here to get it working right.

here is the code for the registration page which fills the database with registration information....

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $db =connect('jsnow_jsnow','******');
        if($db!=false)
        {
            register($db);
            echo "User registered";
        }     
    }

    function connect($dbuser, $dbpassword)
    {
        try
        {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login',$dbuser,$dbpassword);
            return $db;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e;
            return false;
        }
    }

    function register($db)
    {
        $user  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = shal($_POST['password']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['e_mail']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO members(username,password,email)   values('".$user."','".$password."','".$email."')";
        try
        {
            $db->eginTransaction();
            $db->exec($query);
            $db->commit();
            echo "commit succesful";
        }
        catch(Exception $e){}
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost/projects/login/rigister/php" method="post">
            username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
            password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
            email<input type="text" name="e_mail"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What output do you have when you press the submit button?

Comment: `$db->eginTransaction();` - I'd think the missing 'b' after the arrow is relevant.

Comment: @RobertRozas the entries in the fields clear and the url changes from
http://vps8383.inmotionhosting.com/~jsnow/login.php
to
http://vps8383.inmotionhosting.com/~jsnow/login.php?username=jpitty3153&password=missysnow2005
and that is the only on screen change no errors or issues but its not displaying the welcome messages....

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Also, SHA1 is not considered a safe form of storing user passwords. Read more about it [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Comment: @DiMono the b wasn't missing in the script that was not working i guess it was just leftover junk that wasn't replaced in the registration code good catch though

Comment: I think i find the bug...posting answer

Comment: You're also checking $_POST['user'] instead of you're input name username

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
echo "WELCOME you are logged in";   
}
```

To this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
echo "WELCOME you are logged in";   
}
```

Comment: You'll never see this(the welcome message) though unless you refresh the page.